# Decimal to binary without storing remainders

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

EDIT: My question was not well thought out.

This version gives a clearer idea of what I'm looking for:

```
def dec_to_bin(n):
    result = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            print(f"1 * 2 ^ {'some value related to n'}")
        else:
            print(f"0 * 2 ^ {'some value related to n'}")  
        n //= 2
        
print(dec_to_bin(13))
```

How do I calculate `some value related to n` at each step?

---

All the decimal to binary algorithms I've seen store remainders on division by 2 and build the result at the end. Is there a way to do the conversion that accumulates the result as it iterates?

Something like this:

```
def dec_to_bin(n):
    result = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            result += 999 # some power of 2 calculated from n.
        n //= 2
    return result
        
print(dec_to_bin(9))
```

How would I know what value to add to `result` at each step?

Comment: This isn't decimal to binary conversion: a Python `int` is _already_ stored in binary, so it's not clear what your function is supposed to achieve. Your function apparently takes an `int` as input and returns an `int` as output: can you give some examples of those inputs  and outputs to show what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: not clear what you're asking. if n is the number then it's just a number. You can choose to display it in binary or decimal pretty easily. If it's the string representation of a decimal number then you can't use math operations on it like that.

Comment: see also https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod And what's with "some power of 2"? Just multiply the place value by 2 each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the number of division you apply to n in order to get the good exponent :

```
def dec_to_bin(n):
    result = 0
    exp = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            result += 2 ** exp
        n //= 2
        exp += 1
    return result
```

however, the only result would be a function roughly equivalent to equality :

```
>>> dec_to_bin(9)
9
```

because you accumulate result into a number, if you want the binary representation you can change function to :

```
def dec_to_bin_rep(n):
    result = ""
    while n > 0:
        result = ('1' if n % 2 == 1 else '0') + result
        n //= 2
    return result
```

Comment: This answers the question how do I get the power of two. Personally, I would have just multiplied the place_value by 2 each time through the loop instead of adding one to the exponent. I do think it's important to point out that these are done only for exercise, as they are the equivalent of "return n" and "return bin(n)"

Comment: Now this may seem dumb, but aren't those exponents backwards? I mean I'm sure the result is correct, but I would expect the power for larger values of n to be calculatd first. Is that just the way the algorithm works, by keeping track of the smaller remainders on division by higher powers of 2 first?

Comment: I was thinking maybe something like math.floor of log n as the initial exponent of 2?

Comment: well, you can compute the other way around, as you say with logs and floor but that would be another subject ;)

Comment: if so, you would first find the initial exponent (or begin with a large enough value) and check each loop iteration multiply result by 2 and if n is bigger than ```2** exp``` then substract n by this and add 1 to result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want :

```
def dec_to_bin(n):
    result = ""
    exp = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            result = "1" + result
            n = (n-1)//2
            print(f"1 * 2 ^ {exp}")
        else:
            result = "0" + result
            n = n//2
            print(f"0 * 2 ^ {exp}")
        exp += 1
    return result or 0
print(dec_to_bin(13))
```

Output :

```
1 * 2 ^ 0
0 * 2 ^ 1
1 * 2 ^ 2
1 * 2 ^ 3
1101
```